# Acessing private data member using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I'm working on a school project that is basically building a dictionary. One of the options is searching for words with the same definition and printing it.
In my dictionary class I've got:

```
#pragma once
#include "Definition.h"
class Dictionary
{
private:
    /*Private data members*/
    int num_words = 0;
    Definition** book;
public:

    /*Constructors & destructor*/
    Dictionary();
    Dictionary(const Dictionary&);
    ~Dictionary();

    /*Search for existing definition*/
    bool checkCopy(const Definition&);

    /*bool operator overloading*/
    bool operator==(const Dictionary&) const;
    bool operator!=(const Dictionary) const;

    /*Operator = -= += overloading*/
    Dictionary& operator=(const Definition&);
    Dictionary& operator=(const Dictionary&);
    Dictionary& operator-=(const int);
    Dictionary& operator+=(const Definition&);

    /*Input & output operators overloading*/
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Dictionary&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Dictionary&);

    /*Index operator overloading*/
    Definition& operator[](int);
    Definition operator[](int) const;

    /*Sorting dictionary function*/
    void sortDictionary();

    /*Utility functions*/
    int getSize() const;
    bool search(const String&) const;
    void searchCommon() const;
    void findCopy(String&, String&, bool&);
};
```

Then In the definition class I've got:

```
#pragma once
#include "String.h"
class Definition
{
private:
    /*Private class embers*/
    String word;
    String** def;
    int num_defs = 0;
public:

    /*Constructors & destructor*/
    Definition();
    Definition(const Definition&);
    ~Definition();

    /*Overloading = += -= operator*/
    Definition& operator=(const Definition&);
    Definition& operator+=(const String&);
    Definition& operator-=(int);

    /*Overloading bool operators*/
    bool operator==(const Definition&) const;
    bool operator!=(const Definition&) const;

    /*Overloading input & output operators*/
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Definition&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Definition&);

    /*Overloading index operators*/
    String& operator[](int);
    String operator[](int) const;

    /*Sorting Functions*/
    void sortDefinition();
    void sortOrder();
    void sortDupl();
    const String& getWord() const;
    const String& getDef(int) const;
    int getNumDef() const;
};
```

Now I'm trying to search the commons by copying the dictionary and when finding a copy definition for the searched one it deletes it from the copied dictionary. However I get a violation of data and I guess one of the indexes or the getSize/getDefNum isn't returning a normal value:

```
void Dictionary::searchCommon() const {
    Dictionary temp;
    temp = (*this);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
    {
        String comWord((*book)[i].getWord());
        for (int j = 0; j < (*book)[i].getNumDef(); ++j)
        {
            String comDef((*book)[i].getDef(j));
            bool flag = false;
            temp.findCopy(comDef, comWord, flag);
            if (flag)
            {
                cout << comWord << endl;
                cout << comDef << endl << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
}

void Dictionary::findCopy(String& comDef, String& comWord, bool& flag) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*book)[i].getNumDef(); j++)
        {
            if (comDef == (*book)[i].getDef(j) && comWord != ((*book)[i].getWord()))
            {
                cout << (*book)[i].getWord();
            (*book)[i] -= j;
                flag = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Help?

EDIT: This is the project, If someone could check it in his debugger that would be great:
https://github.com/adamorad/Dictionary.git

Comment: You guess? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Step through the code in your debugger to see where it goes wrong. Or reduce the code to a minimal but complete [test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want others to help. There's  too much code here to spot any simple errors, but too little to try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Tried it, can't seem to find why is it accessing non existing objects. I'm adding a github link to the main post with all the code, maybe someone could take a look in his debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're accessing the `book` attribute of your `Dictionary` object.

You're assigning it as an **array of pointers**, with lines like this one, which is fine:

```
book = new Definition*[input.num_words];
```

But you try to access its elements as if it was a **pointer to an array** everywhere in the `searchCommon` and `findCopy` methods:

```
(*book)[i].getNumDef()
```

To fix it, replace it with an expression that first gets the ith element of the array, which is a pointer, and then dereferences it: `*(book[i])`

Or more conveniently in order to access `Definition` methods:

```
book[i]->getNumDef()
```

And you have the same problem in the `Definition::getDef(int idx)` method.

After replacing all these your code runs fine, even though I'm not sure it prints the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still can't get back the def even when I use: `const String& Definition::getDef(int idx) const {
 return (def[idx]->getData());
}` It returns a null and not the string :/

Comment: Just use `return *(def[idx]);` and it works fine. I would also suggest to turn on the compiler warnings: for instance in Visual, the above `getDef` function gives the C4172 warning: _returning address of local variable or temporary_